# Creating custom/more distance of ticks x axis in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Please find my code below (I did not place the updated code for each image here.) The Code below is for the image labeled original :**

```
packages <- c("ggplot2", "dplyr", "quantreg", "officer","tidyverse","here","glue","rvg","viridis","scales")
install.packages(setdiff(packages, rownames(installed.packages())))
lapply(packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

data <- read.csv(file='Spiderplot_data.csv', header=TRUE)
Progressed <- as.factor(data$Progression)
Response <- as.factor(data$X)
Response <- factor(data$X, levels = c("Progressive Disease", "Stable Disease", "Partial Response", "Complete Response")) 
highlight_df <- filter(data, Progression == 1)

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(
    data,
    mapping = aes(
      x = Cycle,
      y = Change,
      group = Study_ID,
      color = Response
        )
      ) +
  geom_point(
    data,
    mapping = aes(
      x = Cycle,
      y = Change,
      group = Study_ID,
      color = Response,
      shape = Progressed
        )
      ) +
  geom_point( # Data set with just points
    highlight_df,
    shape = 18,
    size = 2.8,
    mapping = aes(
      x = Cycle,
      y = Change,
      group = Study_ID,
      )
    ) +
  scale_shape_manual(
    values = c(16,18)
      ) +
  scale_color_brewer(
    palette = "Set1"
      ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    name = "Cycle",
    breaks = c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,30,40,45),
    limits = c(0,45),
    expand = expansion(mult = c(0,0.001))
      ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Percent Change in Lesion SLD (%)",
    breaks = c(-1,-.75,-.50,-.40,-.30,-.20,-.10,.10,.20,.30,.40,.50,.65),
    limits = c(-1,.65),
    labels = percent
    ) + 
  ggtitle("Response Plot")
p

p_dml <- rvg::dml(ggobj = p)

# initialize PowerPoint slide ----
officer::read_pptx() %>%
  # add slide ----
officer::add_slide() %>%
  # specify object and location of object ----
officer::ph_with(p_dml, ph_location(width = 10, height = 5)) %>%
  # export slide -----
base::print(
  target = here::here(
    "demo_3.pptx"
  )
)
```

As you can see the distance between each point on the x axis is linear and equal, is there a way to spread out the distance on the plot between 0-20 and make space between 20-40 smaller?

As you can see I have tried to do this using the expand function, but to no avail, I am using the funciton wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Orginal image**

[image: Original Image]

**Image with scale_x_sqrt**

[image: Image with scale_x_sqrt]

**Image with scale_x_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 3))**

[image: Image with scale_x_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 3))]

While this is as close as we've gotten to what I am looking for, is there a function that allows me to customize exactly where the ticks are on the axis?

Comment: Does using `scale_x_sqrt()` instead of `scale_x_continuous()` help? Also the expand argument is for putting extra padding on either end of the axis, it is not for changing distances between ticks.

Comment: Thats not a bad idea, but I just tried and I will update with link to pic, I doesn't exactly solve the issue though

Comment: I like using `scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 10))`, fiddling with the `10` parameter to define where it should starts shifting from linear to log transformation.

Comment: @JonSpring So this is very helpful, however I wonder if there is away to pivot back to linear and then back to log so that way the packing doesn't rebunch to early

Comment: While this is as close as we've gotten to what I am looking for, is there a function that allows me to customize exactly where the ticks are on the axis?